# Cumulative 90th Percentile Values by Time Period in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, percentile

My goal is to calculate cumulative values of 90th percentile wait times for patients that waited to receive a service at 3 hospitals for 5 periods.

Each period corresponds to a certain timeline (for example, period 1 (P01) means that a patient had a service between April 1, 2018 and May 3, 2018, period 2 (P02, service between May 5, 2018 and May 31, 2018).

My original query is very complex and here is a simplified version of it.
My table consists of 3 columns:

```
 CREATE TABLE Mytable1(
period varchar2(10),
hospital varchar2(100),
 wait_days int
);
```

Then inserting values for wait times (in days), five for each hospital as there are 5 periods.

```
INSERT ALL
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P01', 'NANAIMO HOSPITAL',182)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P02','NANAIMO HOSPITAL',187)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P03','NANAIMO HOSPITAL',188)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P04','NANAIMO HOSPITAL',182)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P05','NANAIMO HOSPITAL',190)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P01','VICTORIA HOSPITAL',230)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P02','VICTORIA HOSPITAL',241)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P03','VICTORIA HOSPITAL',245)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P04','VICTORIA HOSPITAL',237)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P05','VICTORIA HOSPITAL',240)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P01','ARBUTUS HOSPITAL',156)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P02','ARBUTUS HOSPITAL',163)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P03','ARBUTUS HOSPITAL',144)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P04','ARBUTUS HOSPITAL',158)
INTO Mytable1(period,hospital,wait_days) VALUES ('P05','ARBUTUS HOSPITAL',165)
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Now I calculate the 90th percentile wait times by using the analytic version without Group By subquery:

```
SELECT period, hospital,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY wait_days) OVER (PARTITION BY hospital) as percentile
FROM Mytable1
order by period, hospital;
```

Here are my results:

```
PERIOD  HOSPITAL    PERCENTILE
P01 ARBUTUS HOSPITAL    164.2
P01 NANAIMO HOSPITAL    189.2
P01 VICTORIA HOSPITAL   243.4
P02 ARBUTUS HOSPITAL    164.2
P02 NANAIMO HOSPITAL    189.2
P02 VICTORIA HOSPITAL   243.4
P03 ARBUTUS HOSPITAL    164.2
P03 NANAIMO HOSPITAL    189.2
P03 VICTORIA HOSPITAL   243.4
P04 ARBUTUS HOSPITAL    164.2
P04 NANAIMO HOSPITAL    189.2
P04 VICTORIA HOSPITAL   243.4
P05 ARBUTUS HOSPITAL    164.2
P05 NANAIMO HOSPITAL    189.2
P05 VICTORIA HOSPITAL   243.4
```

I get the same 90th percentile for each period. I wonder how I can get the cumulative value of the 90th percentile for each subsequent period. Basically, I need to calculate the 90th percentile based on adding the previous period results expecting slightly different values for the 90th percentile (below is an example of what I would like to get):

```
P01 ARBUTUS HOSPITAL    164.2
P02 (=P01+P02)  ARBUTUS HOSPITAL    165
P03(=P01+P02+P03)   ARBUTUS HOSPITAL    162
P04 (=P01+P02+P03+P04)  ARBUTUS HOSPITAL    163
P05(=P01+P02+P03+P04+P05)   ARBUTUS HOSPITAL    164
```

Could you please help? Thank you!

P.S. I have asked a question regarding the 90th percentile calculations before but it was related to a different issue.

Comment: try group by period and then aggregating

Answer (score 0):

You should add the period to your partition and then use sum over. Your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT distinct hospital, period, 
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (order by cumDays) OVER (PARTITION BY hospital, period) as percentile
from(
select t.hospital, t.period, t.wait_days, c.period cumPeriod, c.wait_days cumDays from mytable1 t
left outer join  mytable1 c on t.hospital = c.hospital and t.period >= c.period
) x
```

p.s. I didn't have access to an Oracle DB so I tried on MSSQL DB and it worked.

**EDIT:** Following Natalia's first comment the answer was edited to return the correct result. Please mark this question as answered if the edited query is now returning the correct result.

Comment: Thank you Hady! Yes, it does calculate the cumulative numbers but unfortunately the 90th percentile cannot be summed, as similar to percentage - when we calculate cumulative values we cannot sum percentages (for volume it works perfect).